# EditorFor id & name convention override

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper, editorfor

I have a simple form for modifying part of a complex model. I can of course pare down the model, but I would like to solve the complex case, because we'll eventually be dealing with the whole model anyways.

I want the rendered input to have a simple Id and Name, but the model name seems to be unmovable.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.CallInfo.Phone1,
   new { @id = "Phone1", @name = "Phone1"})
```

Should output this

```
<input type="text" value="" name="Phone1" id="Phone1" class="text-box single-line">
```

Instead, it outputs this, with CallInfo prefixed everywhere.

```
<input type="text" value="" name="CallInfo.Phone1" id="CallInfo_Phone1" class="text-box single-line">
```

If this can't be defeated, then is there a way to get the `CallInfo.Phone1` parameter to auto-parse into a parameter for the action method? Because this is waaay invalid syntax in C#.

```
public ActionResult UpdatePhoneNumber(Int32 profileId, String CallInfo.Phone1)
```

Again, I realize I could manually retrieve it from the request, like so

```
HttpRequest.Current.Params["CallInfo.Phone1"]
```

But it really seems like the C# MVC4 conventions should play nice together here, making ONE of these auto-magic widgets do the right thing.

**Update:** Following Dmitri's answer, I left the view markup the way it was, with the `name="CallInfo.Phone1"` attribute as generated and modified the action signature to this:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult UpdatePhoneNumber(Int32 profileId,
    [Bind(Prefix = "CallInfo")] string phone1)
{
    // Save it
}
```

In the debugger, `phone1` is null and does not get saved to the database. The post body, captured from firebug, has this to say:

```
Parameters          application/x-www-form-urlencoded
CallInfo.Phone1     8121234567
```

I've also tried capitalizing the `p` in the `Phone1` parameter name to no effect.

Comment: good question... I haven't seen anybody post about model binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If this can't be defeated, then is there a way to get the
>   CallInfo.Phone1 parameter to auto-parse into a parameter for the
>   action method? Because this is waaay invalid syntax in C#.

Sure, using the `[Bind]` attribute:

```
public ActionResult UpdatePhoneNumber(
    int profileId, 
    [Bind(Prefix = "CallInfo")] string phone1
)
{
    ...
}
```

or even better, by defining a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int ProfileId { get; set; }
    public CallInfoViewModel CallInfo { get; set; }
}

public class CallInfoViewModel
{
    public string Phone1 { get; set; }
}
```

and then having your controller action take this view model as argument:

```
public ActionResult UpdatePhoneNumber(MyViewModel model)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: didn't know about the bind. that's kool. saves some serious trouble over building this.

Comment: Now you know :-) But using a view model is a much better approach. So you haven't lost much by the fact that you didn't know it because you already knew the correct way :-)

Comment: Bind is exactly what I want for now. We have the ViewModel and we're passing it to the view already, but I don't want to pass the whole thing back for this edit action that's only touching one field. I know that would be 'doing it right', but we're not at that phase yet. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: While I have your attention, is there any way to override the `editorfor` `name` and `id` attributes?

Comment: It is possible to change the id (by writing a custom editor template), but the name is not possible because it is generated by the underlying helpers. In theory it might be possible but you will have to write your own custom helpers such as TextBoxFor, ... Something I have never needed to do.

Comment: Yes there was a missing closing bracket in my example. Thanks for spotting it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you want CallInfo.Phone1 and Phone1 as arguments to the Action Method. In that case your Model should be a container for a CallInfo Model and Phone1 (string?) param.

```
class bigModel
{
   CallInfoType CallInfo { get;set;}
   string Phone1 { get;set;}

}
```

Pass the same model to your view

```
@model Project.Models.bigModel
```

and use it in signature of your action method

```
    public ActionResult Edit(bigModel);
```

Comment: Quite the opposite: `CallInfo.Phone1` and `Phone1` are the same argument, I only need one of them. I'm already passing the BigModel to the view, I was just wanting to avoid passing it all back to the update method. We'll get there eventually, but for now we're only exposing editor for bits and pieces of the big model. The reason is that we're adding features to an admin user interface and rewriting it as we go, so it's crossing server & technology stacks - the less data we can send back, the better the performance. Not ideal, but that's how the project budget came out.

Comment: yeah a lot of projects unfold that way

Comment: but then you could just pass callinfo